# How to say "he/she knows"?

Tags: words

For example, "He knows that he's a lazy guy" or something like that.

Something along the lines of **he/she is aware of something** + **the thing he/she is aware of**.

Comment: Welcome to japanese.se, as a rule we don't do translations. If you can demonstrate you tried, then we can tell you whether you hit it or not...

Answer (score 2):

“He knows that A” is “彼はAを知っている” or “彼はAをわかっている”.

Your example is “彼は自分が怠け者であることをわかっている”.
The second “he” is translated into “自分” because it means “himself”.